# Bisection Search on the Lowest Payment on Credit Card Debt: Answers are always way off

Tags: python, bisection

My code:

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2

originalBalance = balance
month = 1
monthly_interest = annualInterestRate / 12
low = originalBalance/12
high = (originalBalance*(1 + monthly_interest)**12)/12
epsilon = 0.01
min_payment = (high + low)/2.0

while min_payment*12 - originalBalance > epsilon:
    while month < 13:
        balance = (originalBalance - min_payment)/10 * (1+ monthly_interest)
        if balance <= 0.00:
            low = min_payment
            min_payment = (high + low)/2.0
        elif balance > 0.00:
            high = min_payment
            min_payment = (high + low)/2.0
        month += 1
print "Lowest payment: " + str(round(min_payment, 2))
```

However, I get 26666.0 while I'm actually supposed to get 29157.09. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: balance could conceivably be exactly 0.00 at some point, which your code doesn't handle. one of those if's should be a `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I changed the first one, but I still receive the same incorrect answer. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reset `month` — it gets once to `13`, and then the inner loop never runs again.

```
balance = 320000
annualInterestRate = 0.2

originalBalance = balance
month = 1
monthly_interest = annualInterestRate / 12
low = originalBalance/12
high = (originalBalance*(1 + monthly_interest)**12)/12
epsilon = 0.01
min_payment = (high + low)/2.0

while min_payment*12 - originalBalance > epsilon:
    month = 1          # < -- do this
    while month < 13:
        balance = (originalBalance - min_payment)/10 * (1+ monthly_interest)
        if balance < 0.00:
            low = min_payment
            min_payment = (high + low)/2.0
        elif balance > 0.00:
            high = min_payment
            min_payment = (high + low)/2.0
        month += 1
print "Lowest payment: " + str(round(min_payment, 2))
```

Comment: So, erm, how do I do that?

Comment: Well, thanks, I got rid of that infinite loop! But I'm still getting the wrong answer... I'm supposed to get 29157.09 (+/- 0.01) but I get 26666.0 instead...?

Answer (score 0):

A mistake I think I see is that you say `high = (originalBalance*(1 + monthly_interest)**12)/12`. What this does is sets `high` to the balance times the sum of one and the interest. This is fine. However, you are taking that number and putting it to the power of 12, then divide that by 12. In your code, `balance = 3000`. That plus the two percent is equal to 3060. This number to the power of twelve is over 6.74 e + 41, a number I do not understand. This divided by 12 is still 5.61 e + 40. This number is so long that the program will crash(or be incredibly slow). This must be changed before anything else can possibly work.

Comment: NEVERMIND. I realized that the exponent was directed to the `1 + monthly_interest`, not the total number. SORRY

Comment: My course explicitly says: Monthly payment upper bound = (Balance x (1 + Monthly interest rate)12) / 12.0

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this same exercise, and here's what I noticed about your code:
you wrote:

```
if balance <= 0.00:
  low = min_payment
  min_payment = (high + low)/2.0
```

However, I think that you should have set the high equal to the min_payment. If the balance is less than zero, then you've been paying too much, so your new bisection search needs to find a number lower than your last min_payment guess.